# Debugging simple Ruby class method?

Tags: ruby, debugging, class, instance-variables

```
class DobbsyKretts
  def initialize
    #Receive idea
    puts "Enter an idea, a secret or anything else you want to secretize; hit enter to stop typing and save the file"
    (@idea = gets).reverse.upcase
    #Filename and saving - to encrypt the file
    puts "Enter the file name you'd like to have this saved as; Type PLAN at the beginning for plans and REM for reminders"
    (@file_name = gets.chomp.upcase)
    File::open("DobbsyKrett-"+ @file_name + ".txt", "w") do |f|
      f << @idea
    end
  end

  def unzip
    puts "Do you want to withdraw PLAN or REM"
    response = gets.chomp.upcase!
    puts "Invalid" if !["PLAN","REM"].include?(response)
    file_contents = nil
    Dir['DobbsyKrett-'+response+"*.txt"].each do |file_nom|
      file_contents = File.read(file_nom)
    end
    puts file_contents
  end
end
somethingsomething1 = DobbsyKretts.new
somethingsomething1.unzip


  def unzip
    puts "Do you want to withdraw PLAN or REM"
    @response = gets.strip
    if @response.downcase != "plan" and @response.downcase != "rem"
      puts "Invalid" end
    Dir["DobbsyKrett-"+@response+".txt"].each do |file_nom|
      @value = file.read(file_nom)
    end
    puts @value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `gets` will return a string with the line-ending character at the end which is not what you expected.  To remove it, use the chomp function:

```
@response = gets.chomp
```

It is okay for a method (e.g. `unzip`) to create new instance variables (e.g. `@valueholder`).  In general it's always better for your variables to have the smallest possible scope, so unless you need to read `valueholder` later, you should just use a local variable (remove the `@` from the name):

```
Dir["DobbsyKrett-"+@response+".txt"].each do |file_nom|
  valueholder = File.read(file_nom)
end
puts valueholder
```

Also, `valueholder` is a terrible name for a variable but if you made it a local variable that could be excused.

Also, your block startings/endings are mismatched.  Here's a fixed version of your function that shouldn't result in syntax errors:

```
def unzip
  puts "Do you want to withdraw PLAN or REM"
  response = gets.chomp.downcase
  if !["plan","rem"].include? response
    puts "Invalid"
  else
    Dir["DobbsyKrett-#{response}.txt"].each do |file_nom|
      valueholder = file.read(file_nom)
    end
    puts valueholder
  end
end
```

**Edit:**  You should capitalize `File` to correctly call `File.read`.

Comment: What happens to @response then? How does Ruby know whether you are referring to PLAN or REM to be used in the DIR line?

Comment: Thanks... The last line of the code (look at mine, I updated) is supposed to print all the DobbsyKrett-PLAN... files or all the DobbsyKrett-REM... files. But I only back whatever I create when I initalize my class. Why is this?